# Storing escape Characters in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store some passwords in php mysql database. Problem is my password list have some escape characters. How can Save those records?

Below is the code, i am trying to add.

```
$pwd='\/'vm';
Insert into passwords(password) values ('$pwd') ;
```

Since this table deals with password, i dont have any other option other than storing the escape chrachets.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Don't store passwords in plain text, use a salted hash then 1: your passwords will be more secure and 2: your problem will go away!

Comment: @CD001 Oooops, you're completely right. And *then* use a prepared statement :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) extension and PHP 5.5+, arguably the best way to store passwords now would be something like:

```
//assuming you're retrieving the password from a user-POSTed form under SSL
$pwd = password_hash($_POST['pwd']); 

//prepare the statement
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO passwords (passwords.password) VALUES (:pwd)");
$stmt->bindParam(':pwd', $pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);

//execute (returns boolean success state)
$success = $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$pwd='\/'vm';
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($pwd);
$query = "Insert into passwords(password) values ('$pwd')" ;
```

Comment: Downvoted for invalid code and for recommending the obsolete `mysql_*` extension.

Comment: Your `$pwd` string is still broken, fix that and I'll remove my downvote .